# How to remove skipped tests from html report

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, automation, pytest

I am using pytest for automation. I have so many test cases and have one test cases as skipped test like below,

```
def test_step(index, description):
"""
    Logs the start of a test step.
"""
    # code for print log
```

Now, when any my test file executed and the report is generated, this test_step is also consider as a skipped test case in the report.

How can i remove skipped test cases from HTML report??

Answer (score 4):

By using this, i can ignore skipped tests in html report,

```
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    if report.skipped:
      del cells[:]
```